# renaming the path-names of ExpressJS of two images at a time for a single route

Tags: node.js, express

**What am i doing** :: my current expressjs program is used to rename the `image` location from `temp` to `/public/images/` for a `single image`.

---

- **image key name is** :: `key`
- **I have used** ::  `var file_name=req.files.key.originalFilename;`

---

- Now if i have another image key name :: `key1`
- I have to use `key1` as:: `var
  file_name=req.files.key1.originalFilename;`

---

**How can i rename both the images at the single route at a time so that `both images` be moved to `/public/images/` from the `tmp` location**

---

**app.js**

```
var express=require('express');
var fs=require('fs');
var http=require('http');
var crypto=require('crypto');

var app=express();


app.set('port',process.env.PORT||7002); 

app.use('/Details',express.static(__dirname+'/public/images'));

//.use(express.cookieParser());

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/Details/',function(req,res,next){



        var file_name=req.files.key.originalFilename;
        var file_name=req.files.key1.originalFilename;

        console.log(file_name);

        crypto.randomBytes(8, function(ex, buf) {

                var array     = req.files.key.originalFilename.split('.');
                var type      = array[array.length - 1];
                var name      = buf.toString('hex') + '.' + type;

                fs.rename(req.files.key.path, './public/images/' + name, function(e) {


                        if (e) {
                                res.send(500, e.message);
                                } else 
                                {
                                    res.send("I got the message - This i confirm");
                                }

                });

        });
});

app.get('/Details/',function(req,res){
        res.send("Image displayed");
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'),function(){
        console.log('Express server listening on port'+app.get('port'));

});
```

---

**According to to the way i describe how can i modify the `expressjs` code** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explore node `async`. You could use `async.parallel` to achieve this. This will help you to rename both the images at the time.